# Inserting a row where one of the columns value is concatenated to auto incremented primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm making a web application using php and mysql where a user can add other users to the database, here's the users table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 userId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 username varchar(128) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (userId)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want the username to be the concatenation of a prefix (provided by the user) and the userId, for example if the prefix is 'student' then the username added to database would be 'student'+userId. How can i achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: This cannot be performed in a query within one table. Use stored procedure. But the best way - do nothing. And build this value in the SELECT query when you retrieve it. The prefix can be stored in separate column/table or hardcoded.

Comment: I agree with @Akina. It is bad idea use one column value in another column values in table.

Comment: I'm building the value in the select as you suggested using `SELECT CONCAT(username, userId)` and it got the job done. Thanks.